# Go WebSocket и Android Messenger

Tags: android, golang

Хочу попробовать написать небольшой messenger для android на websocket. В качестве языка на сервере хочу использовать go.

Никак не могу найти в интернете сопутствующую статью, в которой рассматривалось именно использование одновременно двух технологий.

Например, мы написали на Go отправку json, на Android его приняли. Отправили с Android запрос, а на Go его приняли и обработали, например сохранением в MongoDB.

Находил только Go + Web (например Js).
Или чисто работы Android и WebSocket (а как там устроен сервер, не понятно).

Может кто подкинет необходимую литературу или статьи?

Пытался искать GitHub - репозитории, даже самые простые, чтобы писались одновременно и на go и на android (2 репозитория, и commit параллельно, например на go написали присоединение к каналу, а в другом репозитории сразу реализовали это), но я такие не нашел, такое ощущение что такие проекты в private - репозиториях хранятся.

Когда обучался, то я находил например статьи для Android + Rest Full API на PHP, а вот на Android WebSoket + Go, Mongo никак не могу найти

P.S На Android имеется хороший опыт, но непонятно общие вопросы, например, чтобы следить за сообщениями нужно использовать именно Service или что-то другое.

А с Go только знакомлюсь, поэтому эта информация наиболее важна, так как к синтаксису пока не привык

с MongoDB не работал, но думаю разберусь с noSQL database (до этого работал со всеми популярными sql - СУБД)

Например, вот такие:

[Android MessengerPart Messenger](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android)

[PHP Part](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-backend)

Только нужно на Go и на WebSockets

Answer (score 1):

Присмотрись к библотеке socket io (так как сюдя по вопросам на чистых websocket - тебе будет тяжко) вот библотека для go с примерами https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io а вот туториал для android https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: если совсем не понятно я могу тебе микро проект накидать на след неделе